# Счетчик объектов и заявок у пользователя

Tags: python-3.x, django

Итак задача:
На вход получаем отделы (все какие есть в БД).

Необходимо реализовать вот что:
посчитать количество сотрудников в конкретном отделе, посчитать все активные и неактивные объекты, все активные и не активные заявки у каждого сотрудника из этого отдела.

На данный момент получилось посчитать просто количество сотрудников в отделе...

Вопрос такой, есть-ли в Джанго какой ни будь плагин для реализации такого функционала? И как правильно реализовать вот такую задачку...

Большое спасибо за внимание.

---

**MODELS (отделы)**

```
class UserDepartment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField('Идентификатор', max_length=50, db_index=True, unique=True)
    subdivision = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentSubdivision, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subdivision_department', verbose_name='Подразделение')
    description = models.TextField('Описание', default='', blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField('Картинка', default='department.png', upload_to='department_img')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('department_users_filter', args=[str(self.slug)])

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}, {self.subdivision}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Отдел'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Отделы'
```

**MODELS (сотрудники)**

```
class RealUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField('Фамилия', max_length=120, db_index=True)
    patronymic = models.CharField('Отчество', max_length=120)
    phone_number = models.SmallIntegerField('Телефон', default=0, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Почта', max_length=30, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField('Фото', default='user.png', upload_to='user_img')
    description = models.TextField('О себе', default='')
    department = models.ForeignKey(UserDepartment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='users_department',
                                   null=True, verbose_name='Отдел')
    subdivision = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentSubdivision, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='users_subdivision',
                                    null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Подразделение')
    position = models.ForeignKey(UserPosition, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Должность')
    status = models.ForeignKey(UserStatus, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Статус')
    active = models.BooleanField('Работает', default=True)
    head = models.BooleanField('Руководитель', default=False)
    trainee = models.BooleanField('Стажер', default=False)
    manager = models.BooleanField('Риелтор', default=False)
    employee = models.BooleanField('Штатный сотрудник', default=False)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**MODELS (заявки)**

```
class GuestUser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=255, default='', blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField('Фамилия', max_length=255, default='', blank=True)
    phone_number = models.SmallIntegerField('Номер телефона', default='0')
    email = models.EmailField('Почта', max_length=255, default='', blank=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(RealUser, related_name='user_guests', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Риэлтор')
    guest_object = models.ForeignKey(RealObject, related_name='guest_object', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Объект')
    date_join = models.DateField('Зарегистрирован', auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField('Примичение', default='', blank=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(GuestUserStatus, related_name='guest_status', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Статус')
    active = models.BooleanField('В работе', default=True)
```

**VIEWS (как-то нужно все это посчитать)**

```
def department_index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        departments = UserDepartment.objects.exclude(slug__startswith='shtat').annotate(
            num_users=Count('users_department'),
        )

        context = {
            'departments': departments,
        }
        template = 'department/department_index.html'
        return render(request, template, context)

    else:
        raise Http404
```

**TEMPLATE.HTML**

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Сводка по отделам компании</h1>
    <br>
    <hr>
    {% for department in departments %}
        <h5>{{ department }}</h5>
        <p><a href="#">Сотрудники: {{ department.num_users }}</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Заявки: {{ department.num_active_guests }} / {{ department.num_not_active_guests }}</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Объекты: {{ department.num_active_objects }} / {{ department.num_not_active_objects }}</a></p></a></p>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: filter это: `RealUser.objects.filter(department=конкретный_отдел).Count()` - количество пользователей в конкретном отделе

Comment: Да, но я получаю пользователей через рэлейтед_нэйм... Т.к. с самого начала во вьюхе получаю отдел, и ещё получать всех пользователей из БД не хотелось бы.